# Trying to add new column with DENSE_RANK() in sequentially

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands, dense-rank

I'm hoping some examples will help explain the situation.

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    --ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CardNumber ORDER BY ID DESC) AS 'RN',
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CardNumber DESC) AS Rank,
    CardNumber,
    StampNumber,
    AuditDate,
FROM [dbo].[XXXX]
ORDER BY ID DESC, AuditDate DESC, StampNumber DESC
```

I've read up on DENSE_RANK() and it's the closest to what I'm looking for but not quite there.
Running this block of code gives me

| ID | Rank | CardNumber | StampNumber | AuditDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | 1 | 3 | 20 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 45 | 1 | 3 | 20 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 44 | 2 | 2 | 40 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 43 | 2 | 2 | 30 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 42 | 2 | 2 | 20 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 41 | 2 | 2 | 10 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 40 | 3 | 1 | 40 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 39 | 3 | 1 | 30 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 38 | 3 | 1 | 20 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 37 | 3 | 1 | 10 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 36 | 1 | 3 | 40 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 35 | 1 | 3 | 30 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 34 | 1 | 3 | 20 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 33 | 1 | 3 | 10 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |

The result I'm looking for is

| ID | Rank | CardNumber | StampNumber | AuditDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | 1 | 3 | 20 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 45 | 1 | 3 | 20 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 44 | 2 | 2 | 40 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 43 | 2 | 2 | 30 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 42 | 2 | 2 | 20 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 41 | 2 | 2 | 10 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 40 | 3 | 1 | 40 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 39 | 3 | 1 | 30 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 38 | 3 | 1 | 20 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 37 | 3 | 1 | 10 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 36 | 4 | 3 | 40 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 35 | 4 | 3 | 30 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 34 | 4 | 3 | 20 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |
| 33 | 4 | 3 | 10 | 2022-03-07 03:45:50.343 |

I'd like the dense rank to still group the rank by the CardNumber but need the rank column to grow sequentially instead of resetting.
I'm looking to only grab the top 3 ranks.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, as your title suggests, why have you tagged [[tag:mysql]] too?

Comment: The rank column isn't resetting, it would only do that if you had a `PARTITION BY`. It's just counting all the individual `CardNumber` values. If you remove the final `ORDER BY ID DESC, AuditDate DESC, StampNumber DESC` you will see what it's doing. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve: do you want each group of `CardNumber` sets (as ordered by `ID DESC`) to have a new rank?

Comment: @Charlieface I see what it does without the Order By, but this is the order i need it in.
I realize the data is the same but this is a worse case scenario. 

As the example shows..
There is Card number 1, 2 & 3, each with a Stamp Number, !0, 20, 30 & 40.

I need the top 3 card numbers to be grouped with their respective stamp number but not together, so the order will always be Card 3 2 1, 3 2 1, ect.

Looking to get the latest 3 cards only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a type of *gaps-and-islands* problem.** You are trying to get a ranking number for each group of identical `CardNumber` values (with no gaps), when ordered by `ID DESC`.

You cannot use `DENSE_RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` for this, because they will place all rows with the same `CardNumber` value together.

There are a number of solutions. Here is one:

```sql
WITH PrevValues AS (
     SELECT *,
       IsNewCardNumber = CASE WHEN CardNumber = LAG(CardNumber) OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC)
                        THEN NULL ELSE 1 END
     FROM XXXX
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Rank = COUNT(IsNewCardNumber) OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC),
  CardNumber,
  StampNumber,
  AuditDate
FROM PrevValues;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=34a10bea63152b254b79dd5a35b94da2)

Comment: I see i was on the wrong track with the DENSE RANK, this Lag and your solution has helped. Thank you !